# Exiting while(1) loop in C programming

Tags: c, while-loop, return-value, infinite-loop

I am doing examples for my `C` programming class. And one of the examples is this:

Update: Difference between `return 0;` and `break;`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

while(1)
{
  printf("Enter number: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  if (num==2)
   {
      return 0;
   }
  else
   {
      printf("Num = %d", num);
   }

return 0;
}
```

I know that `while(1)`is an infinite loop. 
To get out of loop I used `break;`normally.

But, in this example when `num=2` it gets out of loop.

I don't understand how `return o;` effects the `while(1)` loop ?

Comment: I only used return 0; at the end of the main program. It is the first time I see it inside a loop. I know that if the program executed successfully, then it will return 0.

Comment: Show the rest of the code, i.e. make a [mcve] please. It has important context for the explanation of what the return does.

Comment: Some of those commenting IMHO really need to read https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Comment: Don't be hard on me guys :D  I am studying these by myself and sometimes very simple parts of the program confuse a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To better explain to you lets add few lines to your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (num==2)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Num = %d", num);
        }
     }

     printf ("BYE\n");
     return 0;
}
```

and lets put `break` instead of `return 0;`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (num==2)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Num = %d", num);
        }
     }

     printf ("BYE\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Output of first code would not include the message "BYE", where second code would.

So the to sum up `return` terminates function and does not execute anything below it, where break terminates loop and program does not execute remaining lines with in the loop.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. My confusion was exactly on these two.

Answer (score 4):

```
return 0;
```

exits the function you are in, with a return value of `0`.  So, if it leaves the function, it obviously is leaving the `while` loop which is in the function.

Answer (score 4):

`return` immediately exits the function - regardless of the work program was doing.

If you were executing the `while(1)` loop in the `main` function, `return` would immediately exit `main` function, which means it will quit the program and exit the infinite loop as well.

If you were executing the loop in other function, say `foo`, `return` would still immediately exit the `foo` function, which still means it would exit the infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, as I understood, it doesn't matter the place of the return 0;

Comment: Whenever the program line reaches return 0; the program terminates by returning zero

Answer (score 2):

return terminates the function and returns control to the calling function (if any). 
That's why it breaks out of any loop, conditional or other controlling construction.

The returned value is of no importance in this respect.